# Applied to Ph.D. position in Norway; process has taken 5 months so far

Tags: application, norway

So I applied to two positions in Norway, and the process has been slow. I know it would be slow but not this slow.

For the 1st position: I knew it would open because of a professor who was interested in my work and said would support my application.

Three months after closing did a committee was made to evaluate candidates saying a report would be sent soon as possible. This has been in September and we are almost two months out since that message was sent.

The 2nd position: Waiting since August, they quickly established a committee and second time they apologized for the delay.

With all of this, does it mean that I am still likely in the running for the position if I am receiving these messages. Am I no? Would it negatively impact my chances if I asked how the application process was going to the professor who was interested in my work for the first position?

Comment: Are you still in the running? Maybe? Norwegian academic hiring processes are known to be slow, see e.g. [Hiring Process in Norway for Postdocs](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/68777/17254), [What is the typical time between application and contact for a postdoc on Norway?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/167653/17254)https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/167653/17254